# PowerShell: Count files in a given name directory and subfolders

Tags: powershell

I need to count files inside given folders

example:

```
Folder A
Folder B
Folder C
```

For each folder I need to count how many files there are, and at the end sum the total.

What is the best to way to do this?

Comment: Though a kind soul gave you an answer. Know that, SO/SU, et all, does have rules to follow: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$DirList=@('C:\temp\BATCHHISTOCRE', 'C:\temp\tmp', 'C:\temp\444')

$DirList | %{

    [pscustomobject]@{
    Dirname=$_
    NbFile=(Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -File).Count # Add -recurse if you want all tree into your dir
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeppers, but this will error if the folder path has no files.

Comment: Not on my computer look my picture

Answer (score 0):

Tagging on to ***@Esperento57:***, helpful answer.

Yeppers, it does work, but it will also error off if the folder path has no files; whereas using `Measure-Object` in the mix, can address that.

```
$DirList = @('D:\Temp\AddressFiles',
'D:\Temp\BonoboGitServer',
'D:\Temp\Book'
)

$DirList | 
ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Dirname = $PSItem
        NbFile  = (Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem -File).Count
    }
}
# Results
<#
Dirname              NbFile
-------              ------
D:\Temp\AddressFiles      3
The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:8 char:5
+     [pscustomobject]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

D:\Temp\Book              4
#>
```

Whereas using the `Measure-Object` cmdlet, addresses the issue...

```
$DirList = @('D:\Temp\AddressFiles',
'D:\Temp\BonoboGitServer',
'D:\Temp\Book'
)

$DirList | 
ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Dirname = $PSItem
        NbFile  = (Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem -File | 
                  Measure-Object).Count
    }
}
# Results
<#

Dirname                 NbFile
-------                 ------
D:\Temp\AddressFiles         3
D:\Temp\BonoboGitServer      0
D:\Temp\Book                 4
#>
```